# jQuery select markup inside script tags from backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone.js and the templates are within script tags.  I have a plugin that's iterating all input fields using jQuery selectors.  It's not getting the inputs within the script tags.

Any idea's how to obtain attributes from html defined inside script tags?

Thank you!

Comment: We need to see code, but I am assuming your jQuery is running before the template is rendered (HTML is in DOM).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<script>` elements are essentially black boxes as far as the DOM is concerned, they just hold data that the DOM doesn't care about (specifically, they hold [non-replaceable character data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/script.html), not markup). So, if you do `$('input')`, you won't find the `<input>`s that are inside `<script>` elements because, well, there aren't any `<input>` elements inside the `<script>`s, just character data (i.e. strings) that contain the character sequence `'<', 'i', 'n', 'p', 'u', 't', ...`.

For example, if you have this HTML:

```
<div></div>
<script id="tmpl" type="text/x-underscore-template">
    <input name="{{name}}">
</script>​
```

Then this:

```
console.log('divs: ' + $('div').length);
console.log('inputs: ' + $('input').length);
```

will tell you that there is one `<div>` and zero `<input>`s and it will be telling the truth. If you need to look inside the `<script>`, you'll have to turn that character data into HTML by hand with something like:

```
var $inputs_in_script = $($('#tmpl').html()).filter('input');
```

The length of `$inputs_in_script` would be one.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/64kjq/

If you're processing your `<script>`s with a template engine then you'd have to call your plugin on the HTML that the template engine gives you. Then the plugin will find the `<input>`s because they will be real `<input>` elements rather than strings that look like `<input>` elements.